# What is SQL Server Rand Function algorithm?

Tags: sql-server, algorithm, function, t-sql, random

1. I want to know the exact algorithm of SQL Server 2005 `RAND` function
2. Is there any time factor involved in the logic?

I have searched in the web and couldn't find any details. Some people believe that the `RAND` function is not fully random and by having enough sample they can predict the next one.

Comment: It's not random. It's [pseudo-random](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177610.aspx). There is a difference.

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/183051/htg-explains-how-computers-generate-random-numbers/

Comment: https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/2981/what-algorithm-does-rand-in-sql-server-use.html

Comment: Thanks. Although I haven't used any seed I only used RAND() function. Is it still using static seed behind the scene? Or is it predictable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `RAND()` generates numbers based on the seed parameter.

Syntax: `RAND ( [ seed ] )`

Per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177610.aspx),

- If seed is not specified, the SQL Server Database Engine assigns a
  seed value at random.
- For a specified seed value, the result returned is always the same.
- For one connection, if `RAND()` is called with a specified seed value, all subsequent calls of `RAND()` produce results based on the seeded `RAND()` call.

For example, if you run this code in multiple connections (even on multiple databases or database servers at different times)

```
SELECT RAND(100), RAND(), RAND()
```

you will get same results, below.

```
(No column name)    (No column name)    (No column name)
0.715436657367485   0.28463380767982    0.0131039082850364
```

So if some one can predict the seed value you used, they may be able to guess resulting random numbers.

That should confirm that `RAND()` definitely does not use time or mac address kind of inputs into the algorithm.

[This page at sql-server-helper.com](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/generate-random-numbers.aspx) suggests using `NEWID()` as the better way of generating unique random numbers. But NEWID() is available on SQL 2008 or later.

```
SELECT ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS INT)) AS [RandomNumber]
```

Disclaimer: I am not associated with www.sql-server-helper.com.

Comment: Thanks. Although I haven't used any seed I only used RAND() function. Is it still using static seed behind the scene?

Comment: @Barsham If no seed is specified, SQL server assigns a "random" seed. I don't find any docs on how random this seed would be. But I tried on different connections and servers w/o seeding, I got different RAND() output, but it still does not confirm that the seed would not repeat. This seed is used for the life time of connection, so on a longer living connection, hackers may take the RAND numbers sequence you generated and look up those against their database of random number to guess the seed and then predict the next random number. May be that's what your security team is concerned about?

Comment: Thanks. But it does not guarantee that is predictable. Having suspicious does not prove otherwise.